# How to relate API credential with APP Id in Paypal sandbox envoirment

Tags: android, paypal

I registered on https://developer.paypal.com/ and got 3 information

- API Username
- API Password
- Signature

API Password  Signature

I am developing a android app. I want to integrate with Paypal. Android  developer documentation says you require the AppId. I am hoping it should generated by same user name , by which I have generated above information. But I am not able to figure out how to generate the AppId. I can find a link inside above mention URL.
Any help? or link to read ?

Answer (score 1):

For Sandbox, AppID is APP-80W284485P519543T

See doco just below Figure 5 on this page:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/paypal-sandbox-getting-started-guide

Comment: Thanks, looks it will work. Just one doubt it mentions it is for adaptive payemnents and I am using express checkout. It is like android -> my web Server ->  Paypal. Hope it work fine with that?

Comment: Yes, there is only the one AppID for Sandbox across all their crazy product names... but once you get to Production, the calls that you are allowed to make are tied to the AppID that was assigned to your approved application code. The schematic for data flow you have is correct. Also, since you are doing android, you might also look at this:https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/paypal-apis-and-running-chapter-5-paypal-mobile-express-checkout